# Android: RecyclerView with CoordinatorLayout, first item stops slightly right before going behind status bar?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, coordinator-layout

I have a `recyclerView` in conjunction with a `coordinator layout`
and I've come across a small problem. When you scroll the list down and the first item is about to pass the status bar, it always has a hitch or stops for about a millisecond before continuing. It's very subtle but noticeable. Here is a gif and watch my cursor. When the first item is about to pass the status bar, my cursor moves but the list doesn't. This is very annoying! It happens on the phone as well as emulator.

Please look at gif for clarifcation:
http://i.imgur.com/80A5YNL.gifv

What i noticed was the faster you swipe the less you notice the hitch. Also the hitch is only reproduced after first taking your finger off the screen, have the first item fully visible, and then scroll down the list super slow until first item goes behind status bar.

This is the activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MainAdapter());
}
}
```

Recycler View Adapter

```
public class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.MainViewHolder> {
private String[] FRUITS = new String[] { "Apple", "Avocado", "Banana",
        "Blueberry", "Coconut", "Durian", "Guava", "Kiwi", "Jackfruit", "Mango",
        "Olive", "Pear", "Sugar-apple", "Orange", "Strawberry", "Pineapple",
        "Watermelon", "Grape", "PassionFruit", "DragonFruit", "Honey-dew",
        "Cantaloupe", "Papaya"};

public MainAdapter (){
}

public class MainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView mTextView;

    public MainViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_list_item);
    }
}

@Override
public MainViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return new MainViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MainViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mTextView.setText(FRUITS[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return FRUITS.length;
}
}
```

My code is simple and can't find anything that can cause this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has got to be a bug or maybe it is intended behavior. I am not sure, but I finally found the solution to this problem.

Make sure your `list_item.xml` for the `RecyclerView` is clickable and the hitch / hiccup will be gone:

`android:clickable="true"`

This took me days and countless hours to debug and figure out. Hopefully some one can find this helpful.